# Transpiled code throws error when masking a parameter with an object variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

We tried to port the following code to ES6:

```js
function apitest(data) {
    data.cb(true);
}

function test(cb) {
    apitest({cb: function(data) {
        commit(cb,data);
    }});

    function commit(cb,data) {
        cb(data);
    }
}

test(data => {
    document.write(data);
});
```

It might look a little confusing, but it does what we expect (return true) and does not throw errors.

However, Babel transpiles it to:

```js
"use strict";

function apitest(data) {
    data.cb(true);
}

function test(_cb) {
    apitest({ cb: function cb(data) {
            commit(_cb, data);
        } });

    function commit(_cb, data) {
        cb(data);
    }
}

test(function (data) {
    document.write(data);
});

//# sourceMappingURL=test4.js.map
```

This code fails since the `cb()` called inside `commit()` does not have an underscore.

Regardless of whether you should write this kind of code: Is our syntax faulty or is this a bug in Babel?

My understanding is that the definition of `cb` inside the object should mask the passed parameter. Babel assigns different names to the variable used in the object and in the enclosing function while giving a name to the anonymous function (why would it do that anyway?). After that, it should rename the function call inside `commit()`.

Comment: It works using this es6 fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ihw471ae/

Comment: Looks like the issue here is that Babel is giving anonymous functions in object literals the same name as the key itself. Great for debugging, not good for your use case. Seems to be thinking that the newly created `function cb` is accessible from `commit()` but it's obviously not. You should file a bug :)

Comment: Looks like a bug in babel that you should report.

Comment: I also think it is a bug in babel

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Babel 5 and it's fixed in Babel 6.

Comment: This does seem to be the answer.

Comment: We filed a bug report which got fixed (quite fast, I might add).